# SQL Server Page File On 3TB San Drive

Tags: windows, virtual-memory

We have a Windows Server 2008 R2 box with 288GB of RAM.  The system has created a page file about about the same size.  This is expected, however, when I try to move the file to a SAN drive that is mounted as a 3TB GPT disk, the tool doesn't see all the available space.  Windows reports the correct free space in every location I can look, except for the Virtual Memory GUI tool.  Can someone tell me why and/or how to fix it so I can put the page file on this 3TB drive?  The tool reports 203,965 MB free when the drive as over 2.5TB free.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but a 300GB page file isn't necessary in almost all cases. Do you have a reason for wanted a page file that large other than that it is the default? On a BSOD, do you *really* want for 300GB to be written out of RAM to a full dump file? Can you even analyze a 300GB dump if you had to?

Comment: I have it set to "System managed size", that is what it picked by default.  I usually keep them the same size or bigger than the size of RAM.  Could I analyze it, I believe so but I have never tried yet.

Comment: We generally keep our page file small on SQL Servers in an attempt to force SQL to not page swap SQL data.  With 288GB of RAM, you could probably do the same thing.  Which isn't really the answer to your question, except that you could probably move a smaller swap file anywhere, but probably wouldn't need to.

Comment: @KatherineVillyard while I agree with the notion that most servers don't need swap > 6-8GB, have you considered granting your SQL Server service accounts "Lock Pages in RAM" so that they don't unnecessarily swap out inactive pages in the first place?

Comment: No, but (despite the fact that they don't generally swap, due to having 256GB of RAM) that's not a bad idea.  It's something one of my predecessors started that's become A Tradition.

Comment: @MDMarra - please add your comment as answer.  After much research, I have decided to go with a smaller 100GB page file, which takes care of the issue I was seeing with the GUI tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, there's no need for a pagefile that approaches 300GB. There are a few reasons why you might want your pagefile to be as large as your RAM on Windows:

1. A crash (BSOD) will be able to dump the whole system RAM to a crash dump. Good luck analyzing a 300GB crash dump or sending it to Microsoft for analysis. You're better off with minidumps in this case.
2. You have an application that's trying to *commit* double the system RAM, which will cause out of memory crashes. If you have 288GB RAM and this is happening, you *really* need to add more RAM and not rely on the pagefile. I can't imagine having 200GB+ of *committed* memory on the pagefile. Your storage admin will probably kill you in your sleep.

Other than that, there's not really a benefit to having (pagefile == RAM) on a server. You're better off profiling your application, checking out how many committed bytes are typically in use, and if that is larger than your RAM, take the leftover and adding a comfortable overhead and using that value for your pagefile.

For example, if you have 288GB RAM and you typically have 300GB of committed memory, you might want a 20GB pagefile (12GB for paging to satisfy your memory commitment requirements + 8GB for overhead).